# How do I mark a link only answer for deletion?

Tags: support, flagging

[This answer](https://diy.stackexchange.com/a/210192/34147) was rather poor and one of quite a number by a brand new user spewing generally poor answers yesterday.

The user came back and edited out the questionable text, but now, it's effectively a link-only answer.

Since link-only answers aren't really acceptable, how do I flag it for deletion now? I'm not seeing a "link-only" flag option:

[image]

What is the appropriate course of action here?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using "Very low quality" is fine for a link-only answer. If the answer can be salvaged with an edit, I'd recommend that over a flag. In this case, we could revert the answer to the previous content and add the link for context. However, I'm seeing the previous answer was considered invalid, so this is likely beyond rescue without the OP coming back to add their own context.

Note that if you see a pattern of posts being edited later with a link by a user, it's also worth looking out for spam since that's an occasional technique to get around many of our normal methods to catch spammers.

Comment: Thanks. As you may have noticed, if you looked at the answer (I presume you did), I did put a comment suggesting that he make it a not-link-only answer. I try to give people, especially new people, time to make edits before flagging, but I don't always remember to go back to follow up...

Comment: Also, do mods read the comments when looking at flags? I often put a comment on, then flag with "no comment needed", since I've already made the comment

Comment: @FreeMan We usually do. Sometimes I slip, and in this case read the comments after trying to fix it. It's possible for someone to edit their deleted answer and have a mod return to undelete it, so if the answer is far enough gone, I sometimes do that instead of trying to remember to return later.

Comment: Also, there are some SE sites where *Not an Answer* is the accepted flag for link-only answers.  As the link is not, of itself, an answer.